# How to stop duplicate correlations in table of Spearman Rho correlations in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I used the following code to make a table of Spearman Rho correlations for a CSV file with 2+ columns in R:

```
> myDataset <- read.csv(file.choose())
> attach(myDataset)
> spearmanRhoTestData <- cor(myDataset, use="complete.obs",method="spearman")
```

However, in my table (spearmanRhoTestData), the correlation between any two variables will show up twice (like the following):

```
    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
Var1  1   0.5  0.7 0.9
Var2  0.5  1   0.3 0.6  
Var3  0.7  0.3  1  0.2
Var4  0.9  0.6  0.2 1
```

Is there any way I could write code in R to get rid of the correlation values (ex: between var1 and var2) from showing up twice in the entire table??

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your original data? ! Use `dput(head(my_data,10))` for instance.

Comment: Not sure exactly how you want your output to look like, but you can try if this is OK for you: `spearmanRhoTestData[upper.tri(spearmanRhoTestData)] = NA;
spearmanRhoTestData` .This will replace all the upper triangle part of the matrix with `NA`s.

Comment: Thanks! spearmanRhoTestData[upper.tri(spearmanRhoTestData)] = "" worked for me

Comment: Keep in mind that the `= ""` will update your values from numeric to character, in order to match the `""` value. You might face some difficulties if you want to further process your data. If it's just for viewing / presentation purposes it's OK. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach assuming that you want to keep a correlation matrix format is

```
# set upper triangle values to NA
spearmanRhoTestData[upper.tri(spearmanRhoTestData)] = NA

# visualise updated matrix
spearmanRhoTestData
```

Here's an alternative approach, using the `corrr` package, which will give you a reshaped correlation dataframe, without duplicates:

```
library(corrr)

# get correaltion matrix
tbl = correlate(mtcars)

# set upper triangle values to NA
tbl[upper.tri(tbl)] = NA

# reshape and omit NAs
stretch(tbl, na.rm = T)

# # A tibble: 55 x 3
#     x     y     r
#  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 mpg   cyl   -0.852
# 2 mpg   disp  -0.848
# 3 mpg   hp    -0.776
# 4 mpg   drat   0.681
# 5 mpg   wt    -0.868
# 6 mpg   qsec   0.419
# 7 mpg   vs     0.664
# 8 mpg   am     0.600
# 9 mpg   gear   0.480
# 10 mpg   carb  -0.551
# # ... with 45 more rows
```